# How to have a class contain a list of pointers to itself?

Tags: c++, list, linker-errors, circular-dependency

I'm making a game in C++. In this game, there is a list of GameObject pointers. GameObject is the base class for every object one may interact with in the world. Main's job is to act as the referee, so it informs each object about collisions, renders them, deletes them, etc.

The player's character has abilities. Some abilities may spawn projectiles. Each projectile is different, but all derive from GameObject. They must be added to the list so main may see them. I want the list of GameObject pointers to be global, so that objects may push themselves onto the list, but main may still see and update them. As it stands, the game runs if the list is created in main.

There are 3 possible solutions: I put this list in Globals.h, I apply singleton pattern to the GameObject class, or I put this list in GameObject.h, but outside of the GameObject class. All solutions result in errors.

I believe solution 1 results in a circular dependency, as Globals.h defines enumerated values needed by the GameObject class, but the list is made up of GameObject pointers. The first error on the list says "GameObject is undeclared identifier", and crops up in Globals.

```
//Globals.h
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <list>
std::list<GameObject *> objects;
enum Id{ENEMY, PLAYER, ROCK};

//GameObject.h
#pragma once
#include "Globals.h"
class GameObject{
    public:
        GameObject();
        ~GameObject();
        Id id;
};
```

For solution 2, I am able to compile if I have the list inside the GameObject class, but as soon as I try to push itself onto the list, the linker throws errors. It says "unresolved external symbol". No changes if objects itself is a pointer either.

```
//GameObject.h
#pragma once
#include "Globals.h"
#include <list>
class GameObject{
    public:
        static std::list <GameObject *> objects;
        GameObject();
        ~GameObject();
        void init(){ objects.push_back(this); }
        Id id;
};
```

For the final solution, the linker tells me that main.obj has already defined list  objects symbol. One or more multiply symbols found.

```
//GameObject.h
#pragma once
#include "Globals.h"
#include <list>
class GameObject{
    public:
        GameObject();
        ~GameObject();
        Id id;
};
std::list <GameObject *> objects;
```

I have completely run out of ideas, and I really need this list to be accessible. Solution 1 is most preferable, followed by 2 and then 3. How can I make this list globally accessible? Is it possible? Is there a better way than the 3 ways I've tried?

Update: Solution 1 will compile if I use forward declaring and the extern keyword, but when I try

```
GameObject *test = new GameObject
objects.push_back(test);
```

in main, I get an unresolved external.

Comment: Reminds me of the Badass Bubble Battle Boids game: https://github.com/seanmiddleditch/BubbleBattleBoids It uses an own implementation of a linked list though (a `next` member and static `head` and `tail` updated in constructors and destructors I think).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 and 2 are sound ideas, just a few small gaps in understanding:

## 1 - Declared in globals

Circular dependencies are resolved like this with *forward declarations*. You don't need the full class definition until you either access its members, or need to know how big it is (generally instantiating an object).

The next issue you'll hit is that this causes a seperate `objects` list to be created in every source file which includes Globals.h. You can avoid this by using the `extern` keyword in the declaration (tells the compiler not to allocate space for it just yet) and define it in exactly 1 cpp file without `extern` (memory is allocated there). However, this is more a C-style practice: in modern C++ it's more standard practice to use a static class member (as in 2).

```
//Globals.h
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <list>
class GameObject; // Forward declaration
extern std::list<GameObject *> objects; // Declare, don't define
enum Id{ENEMY, PLAYER, ROCK};

//GameObject.h
#pragma once
#include "Globals.h"
class GameObject{
    public:
        GameObject();
        ~GameObject();
        Id id;
};

//GameObject.cpp
#include "GameObject.h"
std::list<GameObject *> objects; // The list lives here.
```

## 2 - Static class member

Much like the `extern` keyword, when you declare a static class member, it doesn't actually allocate space in the program for the linker to find, so it throws the unresolved symbol error. You need to define storage space in exactly 1 cpp.

Also, it's common practice to make globally accessible members like this `private`, but create a `public` accessor function. This is an easy habit to get into, and will sometimes save you some hassles down the line.

```
//GameObject.h
#pragma once
#include "Globals.h"
#include <list>
class GameObject{
    public:
        GameObject();
        ~GameObject();
        void init(){ objects.push_back(this); }
        Id id;
        // Accessor function
        static std::list <GameObject *> & GetAllObjects() { return objects; }
    private:
        static std::list <GameObject *> objects; // Declaration only
};

//GameObject.cpp
#include "GameObject.h"
std::list <GameObject *> GameObject::objects; // Definition
```

## 3 - Multiple copies

Don't do this.

Every file that includes GameObject.h will end up working with a seperate copy of `objects`.

Comment: Thanks that worked perfectly. I commented out most of the code to keep this problem as simple as possible, so I'm going to slowly drip code back in. Fingers crossed!

Comment: The moment class GameObject is inserted in a list where it is copyable/moveable all those pointers goes "poof" :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by modifying the first case:
Declare the **class prototype** before creating a `list` of the pointers of `GameObject`.

```
//Globals.h
class GameObject; //Defined the class prototype first before including
                  //"GameObject.h"
#include "GameObject.h"
#include <list>
std::list<GameObject *> objects;
enum Id{ENEMY, PLAYER, ROCK};

//GameObject.h
#pragma once
#include "Globals.h"
class GameObject{ //Class body
    public:
        GameObject() {} 
        ~GameObject() {}
        Id id;
};
```

I have defined the `GameObject::GameObject` because when the compiler encounters the line `class GameObject;`, it automatically generates the default constructor, which *conflicts* with the definition we provided to the class earlier.

Hence, we can either **remove** the `GameObject` constructor, or provide an **implementation** of the default constructor, which has been done in the code.

Comment: that works in conjunction with the extern keyword, but then I can't use the objects list in main. Thanks for trying, you got me on the right track.

Comment: @user3263864 I have edited my code, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

You forward-declare the class before you want to use class name to create pointers or references to it.  You don't need the full class definition.  You also should only declare global variables in header files, not define them.  If you define them and include the header in multiple source files, you end up with multiple definition linker errors.  Of course, you do need to define the variable (once) in some source file.

```
//Globals.h
#include <list>
class GameObject;  // forward declaration of GameObject
extern std::list<GameObject *> objects; // declaration of objects
enum Id{ENEMY, PLAYER, ROCK};

//Globals.cpp
#include "Globals.h"
std::list<GameObject *> objects;  // definition of objects
```

Comment: I don't think this will work if Globals.h is included in multiple cpp files without some `extern` usage.